# Are there any commercially available endophytic fungi to protect fruit trees against rusts?

Tags: permaculture

I've read about endophytic fungi that grows in between the cell walls of a plant's cells and offers some protection against bacterial and fungal parasites.  Are there are any commercially available spawns that may be used to protect fruit trees against rusts and other fungal attacks?  If there aren't any commercially available, have there been any experiments that have isolated certain species that I might be able to retrieve from the wild to experiment with myself?

Comment: As a rule, Stack Exchanges don't do shopping recommendations, and with several good reasons. Can we take this over to meta? What we do and don't allow in the private beta, will set the tone for the site's future.

Comment: The question isn't asking for a particular place to shop for spawn, but rather whether there are any spawn that can be commercially purchased, and the name of the spawn.  That's not a shopping question.  That's like saying "Are there LED monitors available on the market yet?"

Comment: @DanielBingham Agreed, I don't think this is off topic as a shopping question. There's definitely some overlap with the gardening site, but that's for another discussion!

Comment: @DanielBingham this never got an answer, and it's too old to migrate to gardening now. Do you want to copy & paste this, and [this](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/167/48) and [this](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/168/48), into new questions over on gardening.SE?

Comment: Not really, they belong here. They are questions about permaculture. Which is to say, sustainably growing food using mutualistic polycultures modeled after a forest's ecology.  They won't get answers on Gardening either.  This is where they belong.  If they aren't getting answers here there are two reasons:  no one really knows yet (very possible with these questions) or we haven't attracted enough experts.  I think, in the case of this question, both are true.

Comment: Also, I will note that two of the three linked questions were closed back when we were over zealously closing permaculture questions and have never been reopened.  Which could be the reason the lacking answers ;)

Comment: I agree this question belongs here.  As a meta comment:  Sources are sufficiently difficult to find in permaculture, that I consider most source questions as good candidates.

Answer (score 4):

It is true that some endophytic fungi have antimicrobial effects on their microscopic counterparts be it of fungal or bacterial origin.

[This paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4423342/) whose study employed the use of fungal extracts from *[Indigofera suffruticosa](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigofera_suffruticosa)* points out that *Nigrospora sphaerica* and *Pestalotiopsis maculans* inocula performed well in a rice culture medium against gram positive and negative bacteria like of the species *Staphylococcus aureus*.

Antifungal activity by endophytic fungi  has also been observed in recent scientific studies. [One study](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031942211002512) for instance, used fungal extracts (whose species were not specified in the abstract of the paywalled article) from *Pinus strobus* and exhibited antifungal biochemical characteristics against the **rust** and [Microbotryum violaceum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microbotryum_violaceum) A.K.A anther smut fungus.

Another study in a paper by Mousa et al (2015) used extracts from [finger millet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleusine_coracana) to perform bioassay experiments that showed antifungal activity against *Fusarium* fungal species (like *F. graminearum* and three others). The strain(s) of anti Fusarium fungi was predicted to be of the *Phoma genus*.

Research on bioactive components from endophytic mycoflora from [*Sesbania grandiflora*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesbania_grandiflora) was conducted using bacterial and fungal indicator organisms. Of the isolated fungi in this study *acremonium* and *fusarium* species exhibited the most potency (Powthog et al, 2013).

[This](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4507527/#!po=51.2987) study further suggests that *Schizophyllum commune* fungal species produces proteolytic enzymes in which inhibit growth of phytopathogens in *Piper hispidum.*

I have not come across information on the commercial availability of the endophytic fungi mentioned above. However, studies can be conducted on their viability with particular tree (like fruit trees since most fungi are host specific) species upon acquiring samples from the wild.

**Edit:** I did not include antifungal endophytic fungi in the initial answer as I missed that [fundamental] part of the question. I hope this little edit answers the question and helps.